# include("file_name") is not working while include "file_name" is

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I was working with WordPress and I required to include require_once('./blog/wp-blog-header.php'); to use WordPress functions outside WordPress when I noticed this strange behavior.

When I'm using `include "file_name"` or `require_once "file_name"` things are working fine, but if I try to use `()` then the rest is a blank page. no result or errors at all.

I faced the same problem earlier but I forgot how that was solve. Is there any reason behind this or this is just happening to me?

Comment: I bet You're doing something wrong.

Comment: if the page is blank and you get no errors, then it's a good bet that PHP error_reporting is switched off. The error will be getting written to the server log, so you can look there to find out what's happening. Alternatively, switch on the `error_reporting` flag in `.htaccess` or `php.ini`.

Comment: I don't know what was wrong with my PC last night. It wasn't working then but now it is working for both situations. @Spudley error_reporting(~0); is on but it wasn't showing any errors either.

Comment: Now nothing is working anymore. If I'm not including that file then is it giving desired output but when I'm trying to include then is gives blank page. I'm posting some data to this PHP file using jquery from WordPress admin page. Is there any security issue that is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is very weird, `include` and `include()` should be equivalent. Nevertheless, `include`, `include_once`, `require` and `require_once` are special language constructs not functions, parentheses are not needed (and IMHO should not be used).

For example, taken from PHP documentation:

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it
>   cannot be called using variable functions.